# PHP: Instead of defining onlinestatus, show only those who are online

Tags: mysql

Yes, so I have this:

```
$query = "SELECT *,
          CASE
            WHEN last_access < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-150 THEN 'offline'
            WHEN last_access < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-80 THEN 'idle'
            ELSE 'online'
          END AS online_status
        FROM users";
```

That'll do if you call online_status, it will either give you offline, idle or online.

How can i change this query to only show the rows of those who are online? I guess something like WHERE last_access < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-150, but im not sure..

Will this do it?

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE last_access < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()+80";
```

It still shows everyone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE last_access > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-80";
```